# Execution Error when change the SATSolver from SAT4J to MiniSAT

Tags: alloy

In my Java code, when i change the SATSolver from SAT4J to MiniSatJNI or MiniSatProverJNI in:

```
A4Options options = new A4Options();
options.solver = A4Options.SatSolver.SAT4J;
```

For instance, to:

```
A4Options options = new A4Options();
options.solver = A4Options.SatSolver.MiniSatProverJNI;
```

And then call:

```
A4Solution currentAns = TranslateAlloyToKodkod.execute_command(null,
                        javaMetamodel.getAllReachableSigs(), command, options);
```

I receive the following execution error:

```
Fatal error:
The required JNI library cannot be found: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no minisatproverx5 in java.library.path
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.translator.TranslateAlloyToKodkod.execute_command(TranslateAlloyToKodkod.java:390)
    at ejdolly.JDollyImp.initializeAlloyAnalyzer(JDollyImp.java:128)
    at ejdolly.JDolly.hasNext(JDolly.java:181)
    at org.testorrery.ForLoopIterator.hasNext(ForLoopIterator.java:40)
    at refactoringTest.RefactoringTest.runTests(RefactoringTest.java:145)
    at refactoringTest.MainRunner.main(MainRunner.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no minisatproverx5 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at kodkod.engine.satlab.NativeSolver.loadLibrary(NativeSolver.java:73)
    at kodkod.engine.satlab.MiniSatProver.<clinit>(MiniSatProver.java:148)
    at kodkod.engine.satlab.SATFactory$5.instance(SATFactory.java:106)
    at kodkod.engine.fol2sat.Bool2CNFTranslator.translate(Bool2CNFTranslator.java:55)
    at kodkod.engine.fol2sat.Translator.toCNF(Translator.java:426)
    at kodkod.engine.fol2sat.Translator.generateSBP(Translator.java:365)
    at kodkod.engine.fol2sat.Translator.toBoolean(Translator.java:343)
    at kodkod.engine.fol2sat.Translator.translate(Translator.java:189)
    at kodkod.engine.fol2sat.Translator.translate(Translator.java:143)
    at kodkod.engine.Solver$SolutionIterator.next(Solver.java:495)
    at kodkod.engine.Solver$SolutionIterator.next(Solver.java:1)
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.translator.A4Solution$Peeker.<init>(A4Solution.java:719)
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.translator.A4Solution$Peeker.<init>(A4Solution.java:709)
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.translator.A4Solution.solve(A4Solution.java:941)
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.translator.TranslateAlloyToKodkod.execute_command(TranslateAlloyToKodkod.java:388)
    ... 5 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ejdolly.JDolly.hasNext(JDolly.java:182)
    at org.testorrery.ForLoopIterator.hasNext(ForLoopIterator.java:40)
    at refactoringTest.RefactoringTest.runTests(RefactoringTest.java:145)
    at refactoringTest.MainRunner.main(MainRunner.java:83)
```

Any help?

Comment: It will probably be easier to get an answer if you specify what operating system you are running under.  On the surface, it looks as if you didn't have a native / JNI implementation of MiniSat where Java could find it.  Are you sure you have one?  Are you sure it's in the Java path?  (Could this be related to your earlier question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957546 ?)

Comment: Hi, i am using windows. And yes, the lib alloy4.2.jar is in the Java Build Path, configured in eclipse. Extracting the alloy4.2.jar, we can see in the \x86-windows folder, some dll's available such as minisat, minisatprover and zchaff. The SAT4J isn't there. However, when i use A4Options.SatSolver.SAT4J option in the Java code, the tool generate alloy instances without any problem.

Comment: i think the implementation in JNI also must exist, maybe in the path org/sat4j/minisat of the alloy4.2.jar library. Apparently this switching (to a different solver such as minisat) would be done internally by the method execute_command in TranslateAlloyToKodkod, since this method receives the object options as parameter.

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar , i see you answered my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908773/alloy-api-resulting-in-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror . I already put the folder \bin, where minisat.dll and minisatprover.dll resides, in native library location . I also extracted the alloy4.2.jar and put the path to the folder /x-86windows where the same mentioned dlls reside, but it still did not work :-( Could you please specify the path did you put in native library location? Did you extract the alloy4.2.jar? Thank you for the attention,

Answer (score 0):

The solution pointed by @Aleksandar in:
[Alloy API resulting in java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908773/alloy-api-resulting-in-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

worked for me on linux!!! But it does not work on windows.

Thank you for all the help !

Answer (score 0):

Alloy invokes native solvers (such as MiniSAT) by using JNDI/JNI. That means that the native libraries must be correctly configured before. If you do not have the library correclty configured, Java will produce a "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" exception.

The Alloy distributable jar includes correctly configured libraries for Windows "x86" and for Linux and Mac in "x86" and "x64". That means that the jar will work in Windows, without any additional configuration, if you are using the Java 32 bits, but not with Java 64 bits. In the other operating systems you can use both Java versions (32 and 64 bits).

You may check [other questions in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957546/why-do-solver-options-like-minisat-minisat-with-unsat-core-lingeling-glucose/34749998#34749998) for the same explanation.

Comment: If you are using an operating system different than Windows, or you want to embed Alloy in a Java project, you may check the answers related to [configure the native libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908773/alloy-api-resulting-in-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror) to be used in Java/Alloy.